# How to retrieve api data from services using angular to display on console

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core

I'm having problems with retrieving data from asp.net.
I'm trying to get all of the reservation restaurant booking data displayed on the console. It only displays undefined on the console.

Below is the service code which is getting data from asp.net core

```
import { Booking } from './../_models/booking';

import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BookingService {
  MainUrl = 'http://localhost:5000/api/Book/';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getBooks(): Observable<Booking[]> {
    return this.http.get<Booking[]>(this.MainUrl);
  }


  getBook(id): Observable<Booking> {
    return this.http.get<Booking>(this.MainUrl + id);
  }

}
```

> ---
>
> below is the app.component file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BookingService } from './_services/booking.service';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  bookings: any;
  modal: any;

  constructor(private bookingService: BookingService, private http: HttpClient, private route: ActivatedRoute ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.bookings);
  }

   loadBooks() {
    this.bookingService.getBooks().subscribe(data =>
      this.bookings = data);
  }

}
```

> Below is the app.module file

```
import { BookingService } from './_services/booking.service';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { TestComponent } from './test/test.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
   declarations: [
      AppComponent,
      TestComponent
   ],
   imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      HttpClientModule,
      AppRoutingModule
   ],
   providers: [BookingService],
   bootstrap: [
      AppComponent
   ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: where or when do you call the method loadBooks() ?

Comment: It’s an async call.. in ngOnInit it doesn’t exist yet. Put the console inside your subscribe.

Answer (score 0):

ngOnInit() will only fire once each time the component is rendered to the view. Your instruction is to log the bookings variable which at the start is an unitialized value.

The loadBooks method should be inside ngOnInit() because otherwise you'll never use it, and thus bookings will never have its value updated.

I would move the console.log() into the subscribe method's callback, and then place loadBooks into ngOnInit()

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.loadBooks();
  }

   loadBooks() {
    this.bookingService.getBooks().subscribe(data => {
    this.bookings = data;
    console.log(bookings);
  }
      );
  }
```

As an aside, since your app doesn't seem to be using bookings for anything other than logging right now, you could also straight out simplify the loadBooks() code to

```
loadBooks() {
    this.bookingService.getBooks().subscribe(data => 
    console.log(data));
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, everyone, and thank you Mar It works :). I was wondering why it would just say undefined and the problem was because the console.log wasn't in the right place.